# Matching data from file with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The file I am pulling the data from consists of the following information

```
<"DATA" 10.21                         
^"DATA" 81.39                         
_"DATA" 38.71                         
"DATA" 84.19
```

Using preg_match, how can I pull the values from each?

I tried `$r = '/<"DATA" (.+?)/';` but it didn't give me the numbers.

Anyone know the correct regex to pull these numbers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/^\s*.?"DATA" (\d+)\.(\d+)\s*$/m', $str, $matches);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/llJBuP).

Comment: Hi alex thank you for your response! The code retrieves every line except the last one, I made a mistake in the post.. there should be no space in front of the last one. Any idea on how to fix this? I updated my post to show you what I mean

Comment: @joe Simply place a `?` after the first `.`. I'll update my post to reflect that now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) function:

```
preg_match_all('/^[<^_ ]"DATA" (\d+\.\d+)$/m', $string, $matches);
// look in $matches
```