# Matching multiple terms with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

This is response to my previous thread ([Matching data from file with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076684/matching-data-from-file-with-regex))

However it was matching only one keyword "DATA", but the file contains 20 others in the same format, but I only want to pull out 3 specific ones including "DATA", which "STAT", "REG", "NET"

Is there anyway match these specific terms?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can use the *Hyperlink* toolbar button (the one with a globe and an arrow) to create links. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: which solution form your last question did you accept?

Comment: @pastacool I just accepted it, alex's answer..

Comment: thx, you have an answer already from kjetilh

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the one you're using now:

```
preg_match_all('/^\s*.?"(?:DATA|STAT|REG|NET)" (\d+)\.(\d+)\s*$/m', $str, $matches);
```

Simply by grouping the different alternatives in a subpattern (seperated by pipes) you can easily match different values. Note that the ?: symbol in the beginning of the parantheses ignores capture for that subpattern.